# Reading different types of file paths from configuration file

Tags: python, python-2.7, configparser

I have the following content in a configuration file (config.txt):

```
[files]
path1 = X:\Dir1\Dir2\target.txt
```

And I parse the file using ConfigParser.

```
config_file = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config_file.read('config.txt')

file = unicode(config_file.get('files','path1'))

with open(file) as f:
    ...
```

The problem is that I'm not sure how to handle the backslash characters and users should be able to specify a network path as below:

```
[files]
path1 = \\server\Dir1\Dir2\target.txt
```

I would appreciate some guidance on how to solve this.

Comment: Seems fine to me, ConfigParser escapes it properly.

Comment: What is the problem ?